# Is Saltstack's minion ID the host IP address?

Tags: networking, automation, salt-stack

Does Salt stack's minion ID correspond to the host IP address that i would be managing?
I'm researching about salt stack for my project and wanted to make certain that my comprehension was good.

Answer (score 0):

The default minion id is the hostname of the minion. It checks `socket.getfqdn()`, `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`. If none of them give any names then it will probably end up as an IP address.

If that's not what you want, then you can [configure it](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/minion.html#std-conf_minion-id) to be anything.

```yaml
#/etc/salt/minion.d/my.conf

id: my-minion-id
```

Comment: Thanks!, Also, since every node would require an agent software installed in an agent based salt stack software, would that also be managed by the master node too? @OrangeDog

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you should have a look at the [installation guide](https://docs.saltproject.io/salt/install-guide/en/latest/)